# camel processor send msg in loop

Tags: java, apache-camel

Why below code is not sending the message again to `direct:stage` ?

`processing file`  only get prints once... **Why** ?

EDIT: Updated code.

```
    final ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {                         

              from("direct:stage").marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson)
              .to("file://stage");

              from("file://stage").unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson, MyTest.class)
              .process(new Processor() {

                  @Override
                  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                      MyTest body = exchange.getIn().getBody(MyTest.class);                                                                       
                      System.out.println("processing file"); 
                      template.send("direct:stage", exchange);
                  }
              });               

        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you create the producer template?

Comment: @MatthewFontana updated code